# Constructing pandas dataframe from a list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let me start off by saying that I'm fairly new to numpy and pandas. I'm trying to construct a pandas dataframe but I'm not sure that I'm doing things in an appropriate way.

My setting is that I have a large list of .Net objects (that I have very little control over) and I want to build a time series from this using pandas dataframe. I have an example where I have replaced the .Net class with a simplified placeholder class just for demonstration. The `listOfthings` in the code is basically what I get from .Net and I want to convert that into a pandas dataframe.

My questions are:

1. I construct the dataframe by first constructing a numpy array. Is this necessary? Also, this array doesn't have the size 1000x2 as I expect. Is there a better way to use numpy here?
2. This code doesn't work because I doesn't seem to be able to cast the string to a datetime64. This confuses me since the string is in ISO format and it works when I try to parse it like this: `np.datetime64(str(np.datetime64('now','us')))`.

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class PlaceholderClass:
    def time(self):
        return str(np.datetime64('now', 'us'))
    def value(self):
        return 100*np.random.random_sample()


listOfThings = [PlaceholderClass() for i in range(1000)]

arr = np.array([(x.time(), x.value()) for x in listOfThings], dtype=[('time', np.datetime64), ('value', np.float)])

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=arr['value'], index=arr['time'])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:**

I think it is not necessary to first make an np.array and then create the dataframe. This works perfectly fine, for example:

```
rd = lambda: datetime.date(randint(2005,2025), randint(1,12),randint(1,28))

df = pd.DataFrame([(rd(), rd()) for x in range(100)])
```

Added later:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((x.value() for x in listOfThings), index=(pd.to_datetime(x.time()) for x in listOfThings))
```

**Q2:**

I noticed that pd.to_datetime('some date') almost always gets it right. Even without specifying the format. Perhaps this helps.

```
In [115]: pd.to_datetime('2008-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-04:00')
Out[115]: Timestamp('2008-09-22 17:57:31.231189200')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PandasRocks. But I don't get how I can apply your answer in my case. Given `ListOfThings` in from my example, can you demostrate how to construct the dataframe with the datetimes as the Index?

Comment: @DoubleTrouble - I have added another line. I think you can use the generator syntax, so Pandas will create the index and the values on the fly. If I am not mistaken, Pandas series are distinct from the numpy arrays.